# reacstrap Modal, oculta tabla al agregarlo al render

Tags: reactjs

Buenas noches quiero agregar una ventana modal en mi pantalla y resulta que al agregarlo como componente, oculta la tabla html, Saludos!!

```
render() {  
            debugger;
            return (  //<div className="deifnirAreaProyectos"></div>
                    <TablaHtml  rows = {this.PonerDatosFilasTabla()} />
                    ,<ModalBasic/> // buttonLabel = "Nuevo"  classNameBtn = "btnNuevo"
                    //<button className = "btnNuevo" color = "success" >Nuevo</button> //estaba en menu, pasar el estilo
            )
      }
```

Este es el modal en la pantalla

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Esta es la tabla que se oculta, cuando uso el modal y funciona cuando quito
  el componente `<ModalBasic/>` del render

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Dentro del componente  , simplemente tengo el modal de la pagina 
  de reacstrap: 
  https://reactstrap.github.io/components/modals/

```
import React from 'react';
import { Button, Modal, ModalHeader, ModalBody, ModalFooter } from 'reactstrap';
class ModalBasic extends React.Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.state = {
      modal: true
    };

    this.toggle = this.toggle.bind(this);
  }

  toggle() {
    this.setState({
      modal: !this.state.modal
    });
  }

  render() {
    return (
      <div>
        <Button color="danger" onClick={this.toggle} className ={"des"}>
               Nuevo
        </Button>

        <Modal isOpen={this.state.modal} toggle={this.toggle} >
          <ModalHeader toggle={this.toggle}>Modal title</ModalHeader>
          <ModalBody>
            Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat. Duis aute irure dolor in reprehenderit in voluptate velit esse cillum dolore eu fugiat nulla pariatur. Excepteur sint occaecat cupidatat non proident, sunt in culpa qui officia deserunt mollit anim id est laborum.
          </ModalBody>
          <ModalFooter>
            <Button color="primary" onClick={this.toggle}>Do Something</Button>{' '}
            <Button color="secondary" onClick={this.toggle}>Cancel</Button>
          </ModalFooter>
        </Modal>
      </div>
    );
  }
}
export default ModalBasic;
```

Dentro del componente  `<TablaHtml  rows = {this.PonerDatosFilasTabla()} />`, solo hay este codigo:

```
import React,{ Component } from 'react'
export default  class tabla extends Component{
    render() { 
        return (
                <table border="1">
                    <thead>
                        <tr>
                            <th>Nombre</th>
                            <th>Clave</th>
                            <th>Descripción</th>
                            <th colspan ="3">Opciones</th>
                        </tr>
                    </thead>
                    <tbody>
                        {this.props.rows}
                    </tbody>
                </table> 
        )  
    } 
}
```

Este seria el código, de mi pantalla donde mando llamar los componentes de tabla y de modal, aqui uso grid css para posicionar los elementos de la tabla, aqui posiciono la tabla, en base a la grilla que ya hice en el componente MenuIndex.
 .

```
import estilo from './../../Estilo/Proyecto/index.css'  (import)
 estilo de la tabla
     .deifnirAreaProyectos{
    border:1px solid #808080;
    grid-column: 2/19; 
    grid-row: 3/19; 
}

table{
    grid-column: 3/18; 
    grid-row: 5/17; 
}

td {
    padding: 2px 5px;
}

.jsonOdd {
    background: #eee;
}


 codigo
 import React,{ Component } from 'react'
import estilo from './../../Estilo/Proyecto/index.css'
import TablaHtml from '../TablaHtml/'
import ModalBasic from '../Modals/'
import {fnConsultarProyectosIdNombre} from './../../../Services/usuarios.service.js'
import { Button} from 'reactstrap';


export default class Proyectos extends Component 
{ 
    constructor(props){
        //debugger;
        super(props);
        this.state = { resultJSONObject  : {} }
        const {token}  = props;
        this.ObtenerProyectosIdNombre(token); //Inicio
    }

    ObtenerProyectosIdNombre  = (token) => {
        fnConsultarProyectosIdNombre(token)
        .then( data => {
            this.setState({ resultJSONObject : data });  //actualiza state, va al render
        }).catch(error => this.setState({ error, isLoading: false }));        
    }

    //*destructurizacion de objeto en parametro
    //De un objeto, sacar el json array y retornarlo
    ObtenerDatosJSONObject  =  ({ JSONOArrayProyectos }) => {
        debugger;
        if( JSONOArrayProyectos === undefined){
            return { idProyecto : 0, nombreProyecto : "Sin resultados", 
            claveProyecto : "Sin resultados", descProyecto : "Sin resultados"};
        }else
        {
            return JSONOArrayProyectos;
        }
    }
    //recibe array de objetos y ponerlo en tabla
    PonerDatosFilasTabla = () =>{
            debugger;
            var arrayObject = this.ObtenerDatosJSONObject(this.state.resultJSONObject);
            let rows = [];
            for(var i = 0; i < arrayObject.length; i++){ 
                    let cell = []
                        cell.push(<td>{arrayObject[i].nombreProyecto}</td>)
                        cell.push(<td>{arrayObject[i].claveProyecto}</td>)
                        cell.push(<td>{arrayObject[i].descProyecto}</td>)

                        cell.push(<td><input type = "button" value = "Editar"/></td>)
                        cell.push(<td><input type = "button" value = "Eliminar"/></td>)
                        cell.push(<td><input type = "button" value = "Detalles"/></td>)
                rows.push(<tr >{cell}</tr>)
            }
            return rows;
    }

    render() {  
            debugger;
            return (  //<div className="deifnirAreaProyectos"></div>
                    <TablaHtml  rows = {this.PonerDatosFilasTabla()} />
                    ,<ModalBasic/> // buttonLabel = "Nuevo"  classNameBtn = "btnNuevo"
                    //<button className = "btnNuevo" color = "success" >Nuevo</button> //estaba en menu, pasar el estilo
            )
      }
}
```

Este es el estilo de mi menu, aqui comienzo la grilla css y de aqui mando llamar al codigo donde estan los componentes que me dan problemas

import menu from "../Estilo/Menu/index.css";

```
 ul {
    list-style-type: none;
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
    overflow: hidden;
    background-color: #333;
}

li {
    float: left;
}

li a {
    display: block;
    color: white;
    text-align: center;
    padding: 14px 16px;
    text-decoration: none;
}

li a:hover {
    background-color: #111;
}

.containerMenu{
    display: grid;
    grid-template-columns: repeat(20,1fr);
    grid-template-rows: repeat(20,35px);
}

.Menu{
     grid-column: 2/19; 
     grid-row: 2/4; 
}

.btnNuevo{
    grid-column: 15/18; 
    grid-row: 4/4;
    margin-top: 5px; 
    margin-bottom: 5px; 
}
```

Este es código ,que tiene el estilo que puse antes y que manda llamar al componente proyectos.

```
import React,{ Component } from 'react'
import { BrowserRouter as Router, Link, Route} from "react-router-dom";
import Proyectos from "./Proyectos";
import Bitacora from "./Bitacora";
import menu from "../Estilo/Menu/index.css";
//import { Button} from 'reactstrap';
//<Route exact path="/" component={Proyectos} token = {this.props.token} />

export default class MenuIndex extends Component {
    render() {

        return (
            <Router>
                <div className = "containerMenu"> 
                            <ul   className = "Menu">
                                    <li>
                                        <Link to="/"   className = "Link">Proyectos</Link>
                                    </li>
                                    <li>
                                        <Link to="/bitacora" className = "Link">Bitacora</Link>
                                    </li>
                                    <li>
                                        <Link to="/grafica"   className = "Link active">Grafica</Link>
                                    </li>
                            </ul>

                            <Route exact path="/"  render={ (props) => <Proyectos {...props} token={this.props.token} /> }/>
                            <Route exact path="/bitacora" component={Bitacora} />
                            <Route exact path="/topics"/>
                </div>
            </Router>
        )
      }
}
```

//Cualquier guia que me puedan dar, bienvenida saludo, si tienen alguna duda con mi problema estoy al pendiente

Comment: Cerrare esta pregunta mi error, era que como eran mas de 1 elementos oucpaba un div como wrapper e iva sin coma.

Comment: <code> return <div>
                        <TablaHtml  rows = {this.PonerDatosFilasTabla()} />
                        <ModalBasic />
               </div></code>